# How to handle modplatforms

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

D2Modd.in is a relatively new platform that enables you to play mods for DotA2. It is fairly popular with 200.000 Users that tried the platform.

How should we handle questions about this platform? Should it get it's own tag or should the DotA2 tag suffice?

Keep in mind that some questions about this platform might get technical (kinda like minecraft mod questions) and therefore I am not sure where they fit.

Thanks for your input!

Comment: LGTM on such questions

Comment: Are there any such questions?

Comment: @TZHX Not that I am aware. I use the platform frequently and this question came to my mind for future cases.